# Lack of colour calibration is hurting my eyes

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, color-management

So on Ubuntu, I can't find any easy way to calibrate the colours on my screen like I can in Windows with the [Color Management tool](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2012/12/calibrate-100015663-orig.jpg). The colours in Ubuntu are too washed out. They're not warm enough for me. My eyes, which are already deteriorating rapidly, are having a lot of trouble adjusting to this cold color scheme and it's making me less productive. I have to have the screen brightness set to 90% every time I'm on the computer, even when there's lots of light from external sources reflecting on the computer scheme--I have to do this because the only way I get accurate colours on Ubuntu is if the brightness is increased. I don't want my brightness to be at 90% all the time. It makes my eyes tired (my eyesight really isn't the best), and decreases battery life for no reason.

Ubuntu's whites are too bright for me, and I can't seem to adjust the white point to my liking, even with programs like Redshift or f.lux. Both tools make the screen redder rather than warmer. They're not like the Windows Color Management tool at all. I've read a lot of answers to this issue on this website, and most of them suggest Redshift. But it's just not working out for me. Unless there's a Redshift command to specifically change reds, greens, and blues. I want less blue.

I also can't get the Redshift GUI working on my laptop. I don't think it's supported on 16.04.

I can't even calibrate my screen through System Settings because the "Calibrate..." button is **always** grayed out. So I can't do anything there.

All I want are the colour balance sliders. That's all I need to adjust the screen temperatures to my liking. Does something like this exist in Ubuntu 16.04.1? Please tell me it does. I don't want to risk my already deteriorating eyesight trying to get used to Ubuntu's colour balance.

I'm using Intel Graphics 3000 (shows up as Sandybridge Mobile in "About This Computer"). But I also have an Nvidia 1000M discrete card that I can switch to. Would switching graphics make a difference here? I hear Ubuntu isn't able to support Intel cards as well as Nvidia ones because Intel won't release drivers for Linux or something like that.

Thank you.

Comment: You might install gnome-color-manager via Synaptic and see if that gets you any closer to creating the required profile.

Comment: Hi, I already have gnome-color-manager but it doesn't let me calibrate my screen. Instead, I realized that I can use redshift to change the gamma on startup. It's not the best, but it's much better than the default Ubuntu color settings. redshift -t 6500k:6500k -g .7:.7:.7 is what I use. Looks like redshift was my solution after all! I'm still holding out hope for a Windows-esque color balance slider to be added to Ubuntu one day.

Comment: Yep Ubuntu wants you to buy expensive colormeters for calibration.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `redshift`! Exactly what I was looking for. I'm in the same boat, a slider to control screen temperature doesn't seem like an outrageous feature to implement. I went with `sudo redshift -t 6000K:6000K`, so much nicer on the eyes.

Comment: @UnityLauncherProblems Hello. Since you're allowed to answer your own questions here on Ask Ubuntu, you can, if you want, add a short answer about how to install and configure Redshift to automatically work on startup.